# Still using windpws xp

Tags: windows

I am using windows xp and can't download Tor after numerous problems with Tor 7.5.6 Now after deleting tor and trying to reload it no luck. I am very technology  challenged so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have a look at my comments starting with https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/17774/still-using-windpws-xp#comment22111_17776

Answer (score 1):

You REALLY should not be using Windows XP with an active internet connection. There are too many security problems that aren't getting patched. You really need to take the plunge and upgrade to any of the modern OS available (Win10, OSX or any active Linux distro). Frankly, WinXP is so unsafe right now that it kinda defeats the point of running Tor at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Appreciated greatly. I have an old outdated computer would Windows 8 or something like that work. Very limited space. Again very technically challenged. I have had issues with Tor on windows xp and had to delete it for safety reasons. Would greatly like to get it back.

Comment: Without knowing the specs of your current computer, it's hard to say what will run effectively.

I also don't know your financial situation, but chances are you can buy a more powerful computer than your current one, complete with a modern operating system, for just a few hundred dollars. This will not only allow you to regain access to Tor, but basically, everything else you do on the computer will likely notice an improvement.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My situation is I'm on disability so finances are bad. I am stuck with what I have for a while. I'll see what I can come up with with windows 7 which my repairman said is the best I can do with my computer and money situation.

Comment: @user23096 for really old machines i recommend OSes like [MX Linux](https://mxlinux.org/), [antiX](https://antixlinux.com/) or [BunsenLabs](https://www.bunsenlabs.org/). they should work on any machine capable of WinXP, but are up-to-date and work with resp. provide the latest versions of browsers and so on... their appearance might not seem as polished as you wish, but security is more important than some (resource-hungry) bling-bling.

Comment: and still the GUI can be customized in far more ways as you are used to from windows, if it looks initially foreign or inconvenient to you. ...the best would be, to create a boot-medium and start exploring and testing in a live-session whats the best for you.

Comment: btw: all 3 of them are based on [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) (one of the largest OSes resp. OS-bases), but with different "low-end" desktop-GUIs... so if you need help (after for sure looking at the distribution-resources itself) guides/advises for your chosen desktop-GUI (if you need assistance regarding GUI-settings), or nearly everything for Debian (if you need assistance for other system-related things "under the hood") should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

For older versions of Tor and other Tor software, see
  https://archive.torproject.org/

https://archive.torproject.org/tor-package-archive/torbrowser/7.5.6/torbrowser-install-7.5.6_en-US.exe